# How to resolve this error in GTK File Chooser Dialog

Tags: python, gtk, filechooser

I have a button that will open a filechooser. But, I got this error:

> (gui.py:9127): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_grab_default: assertion
>   `gtk_widget_get_can_default (widget)' failed
>
> (gui.py:9127): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_file_chooser_embed_initial_focus:
>   assertion `GTK_IS_FILE_CHOOSER_EMBED (chooser_embed)' failed

This is my code:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

def clicked(widget):
    response = filechooser.run()
    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
        print 'ok'
    else:
        print 'cancel'
        filechooser.destroy()

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file('gui.glade')
filechooser = builder.get_object('filechooser1')
builder.get_object('button1').connect('clicked', clicked)
builder.get_object('window1').show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Do you know why this happen?

One more question:
I have a file chooser button. How to make this button not to change path to `(None)` when I click cancel if I already set path on it?

Comment: Regarding your second question - It is normal for it to change to none since you're not choosing anything. I think you could prevent that from happening if you set a default path. I haven't worked with gtk so I can't tell you how to do this but it should be possible.

Comment: Also it'd be helpfull to see the code there filechooser1 is actually instantiated.

Comment: Try putting the `main()` before the creation of the dialog. Does this change something?

Comment: if you mean Gtk.main(), of course the gui won't appearing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

okay, I've got it. to resolve `(gui.py:9127): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_grab_default: assertion 'gtk_widget_get_can_default (widget)' failed`, you should change `can default` from `Common Properties` of your filechooser buttons to `Yes`.

and to resolve `(gui.py:9127): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_file_chooser_embed_initial_focus: assertion 'GTK_IS_FILE_CHOOSER_EMBED (chooser_embed)' failed`, you should change `filechooser.destroy()` to `filechooser.hide()`

Comment: Few years later: `gtk_widget_grab_default: assertion 'gtk_widget_get_can_default (widget)' failed` still present after setting `Can default` to yes on GtkFileChooserDialog. Fortunately setting `Can default` on one of the buttons (e.g. OK button) solves the problem.